# Wouldn't be nice to have a reputation microsummary?

Tags: discussion, reputation, programmers

[There's this thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/firefox-users-your-stack-overflow-reputation-microsummary) made for Stackoverflow which let's you track your reputation on Firefox (check [microsummaries](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Microsummaries#Introduction))

Some guy made an [enhanced version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/firefox-users-your-stack-overflow-reputation-microsummary/12372#12372), it's worth checking it out:

[image]

It would be great to have one for Programmers too.

If only I had *teh skillz*

Answer (score 2):

Did you check on

http://stackapps.com ?

Particularly

https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts

There are many of these and they should work on [any Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: Lovely! Thanks @Jeff

Comment: I didn't found any interesting though.